# Balana and WSO2 Identity Server giving different results

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I have a policy and when i run a request in WSO2 Identity Server i get permit decision as expected. But when i create another sample policy from:

> http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/products/is/4.1.0/modules/distribution/conf/policies/sample-kmarket-sliver-policy.xml

And send my same request again, i get following error:

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
   <Result>
      <Decision>Indeterminate</Decision>
      <Status>
        <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:missing-attribute"/>
        <StatusMessage>Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute</StatusMessage>
        <StatusDetail>
          <MissingAttributeDetail AttributeId="http://kmarket.com/id/role" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" ></MissingAttributeDetail>
        </StatusDetail>
      </Status>
   </Result>
</Response>
```

For some reason request is being run against this sample policy instead of my original policy. Now interesting thing is I downloaded Balana (XACML Engine used by WSO2 Identity Server) source code and ran tests with both policies and my request and i am getting Permit as expected. But when i do the same in WSO2 its not working and i am getting Indeterminate error. I tried both 'Try It' feature and 'Evaluate with PDP' with same results.

Here is the request i used, why is this being applied to the sample policy and not my original policy via WSO2 but not Balana?

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:samhsa:names:tc:company:1.0:subject:provider-npi" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1548797430</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:samhsa:names:tc:company:1.0:subject:provider-npi" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1347570297</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:purpose-of-use">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:samhsa:names:tc:company:1.0:purpose-of-use-code" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TREAT</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">@outlook.com</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-dateTime" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2013-07-12T00:00:00-04:00</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>

</Request>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error,  it seems that attribute finder is not configure. I guess policy has a attribute id called "http://kmarket.com/id/role" But it is not in the request, so attribute finder is called. you need to register an attribute finder to support it... Please find sample attribute finder from here [1].  In balana sample, this attribute finder has been already there with the sample itself

[1] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.entitlement.pip/

Comment: So do i need to register an attribute id? and how can i register it from WSO2 Identity Server Administration console?

Comment: There is no way to do it from Administration console now..  you need to write a PIP module and plug it.. Please check sample PIP   http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.entitlement.pip/